# Make code cleaner by making a method that can accept an enum

Tags: java, enums

So currently, I have some code, that is extremely messy and does the opposite of following dry rules. This is killing me internally, and I would love to fix it, if I knew how.
I have a class called Commands, this have two enums in it. Subs, and Options. What I would like to do, is make a method, such as this one here:

```
public void makeTab(String args, List<String> command, Commands type) {
    if (args.equals("")) {
        for (Commands.type commd : Commands.type.values()) {
            command.add(commd.name().toLowerCase());
        }
    } else {
        for (Commands.type commd : Commands.type.values()) {
            if (commd.name().toLowerCase().startsWith(args)) {
                command.add(commd.name().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if that method actually worked like I wanted it to, I could then do this.

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
switch (args.length) {
    case 1:
        makeTab(args[0], command, Subs);
        break;
    case 2:
        makeTab(args[1], command, Options);
        break;
}
```

Very sadly though, as you should be able to tell, this doesn't work, specifically because of the "Commands type" bit in the method. The problem is, I don't know what to put there to work, I've tried "Class type", "enum type", "Enum type". So, because of this catastrophe, my code is currently looking like this.

```
List<String> comd = new ArrayList<>();
switch (args.length) {
    case 1:
        if (args[0].equals("")) {
            for (Commands.Subs commd : Commands.Subs.values()) {
                comd.add(commd.name().toLowerCase());
            }
        } else {
            for (Commands.Subs commd : Commands.Subs.values()) {
                if (commd.name().toLowerCase().startsWith(args[0])) {
                    comd.add(commd.name().toLowerCase());
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (args[1].equals("")) {
            for (Commands.Options commd : Commands.Options.values()) {
                comd.add(commd.name().toLowerCase());
            }
        } else {
            for (Commands.Options commd : Commands.Options.values()) {
                if (commd.name().toLowerCase().startsWith(args[1])) {
                    comd.add(commd.name().toLowerCase());
                }
            }
        }
        break;
}
```

tl;dr I'm trying to make the last code block cleaner by making a method for the if, else.

Comment: `public void<T extends Enum<?>> makeTab(String args, List<String> command, Class<T> enumClass) {`. this can be called with `Enum.class`

Comment: Can you please explain how I use this and what it does? I'm still very new to java as you can probably tell by my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than taking values yourself, have the caller pass `values()` to you:

```
public void makeTab(String args, List<String> command, Enum[] values) {
    for (Enum commd : values) {
        String lowerName = commd.name().toLowerCase()
        if (lowerName.startsWith(args)) {
            command.add(lowerName);
        }
    }
}
```

The caller would invoke your method as follows:

```
makeTab(args, command, Options.values());
makeTab(args, command, Subs.values());
```

Note that there is no need to check `args` to be an empty string, because when `args` is empty, `startsWith(args)` returns `true` for any `String` value.